# How do I do nested foralls in Drools?

Tags: nested, drools, forall

### Question

Considering these classes:

```
class BookCase { ArrayList<Book> books }

class Book { ArrayList<Page> pages }

class Page { String color }
```

And considering this natural language rule:

> When all pages in a bookcase are black, do A

The trivial approach would be to nest forall clauses, but in Drools can't do that, because forall clauses only allow Patterns (not Conditional Elements, what a forall clause is) inside!

How do I express this in Drools then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually nest multiple foralls if you don't use `forall(p1 p2 p3...)`, but the [equivalent](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch08.html#d0e10463) `not(p1 and not(and p2 p3...))`. Then, to keep individual books and pages from firing the rule, chuck an `exists` in between there.

```
rule 'all pages in bookcase are black'
    when
        (and
        $bookCase: BookCase()
            (not (exists (and
                $book: Book() from $bookCase.books
                not( (and
                    not( (exists (and
                        $page: Page() from $book.pages
                        not( (and
                            // slightly different constraint than I used in question
                            eval($page.color == $book.color)
                        ) )
                    ) ) )
                ) )
            ) ) )
        )
    then
        ...
end
```

Unlike using `accumulate` to create a flat list of all pages, this will maintain the context of `$page`, that is, when a page is put in a constraint with its parent book as in the example above, in this solution Drools still 'knows' what the parent book is.

Answer (score 1):

This is close, but not quite the right thing:

```
rule "all black pages"
when
  BookCase( $books: books )
  $book: Book( $pages: pages ) from $books
  not Page( color != "black" ) from $pages
then
  System.out.println( "doing A" );
end
```

The problem is that this will fire once *for each book* where all pages are black. To assess all pages in all books one could assemble a list of all pages and make sure they are all black:

```
rule "all black pages, take 2"
when
  BookCase( $books: books )
  $pages: ArrayList() from accumulate( Book( $ps: pages ) from $books,
       init( ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); ),
       action( list.addAll( $ps ); ),
       result( list ) )
  not Page( color != "black" ) from $pages
then
  System.out.println( "doing A" );
end
```

Answer (score -1):

While I was writing the question, I think I found the answer myself:

```
BookCase($caseContents : books)
$bookWithOnlyBlackPages : ArrayList<Page>() from $caseContents
forall ( $page : Page(this memberOf $bookWithOnlyBlackPages)
                 Page(this == $page,
                      color == "black") )
forall ( $bookInCase : ArrayList<Page>(this memberOf $caseContents)
                       ArrayList<Page>(this == $bookInCase,
                                       this == $bookWithOnlyBlackPages) )
```

Comment: The second pattern has ArrayList as element of BookCase.books -:- $caseContent, and the fourth pattern assumes that Book is a member of the same Collection and equal to an ArrayList ($bookWitOnlyBlackPages). Make up your mind! - I find that BookCase - Book - Page is the better choice than nesting ArrayLists, so I used this as a platform for my solution.

Comment: Oh :o! That was a mistake. I edited my proposed solution now, changed the Book object in the second forall statement to an ArrayList<Page>. Reason for the mistake is I initially made my question with a Book object (much nicer indeed), but I changed it to ArrayList<Page> because in the real-world situation I am dealing with it is like that and I can't change it. But the way it is now then, would that work? Thanks for all your Drools answers by the way :).

Comment: It still doesn't work - you can't even have tried this code (because `<Page>` isn't acceptable to the DRL compiler). Note that the two foralls are still acting in parallel, so the rule fires repeatedly, even if there's one book with a single non-black page. Sorry, but now I'm signalling a -1.